# return index less than a threshold value in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, threshold

Is there corresponding method to these function in numpy?

```
def arg_less(inarray,threshold):
    return np.nonzero(inarray<threshold)

def arg_greater(inarray,threshold):
    return np.nonzero(inarray>threshold)

def arg_between(inarray,lowerbound,upperbound):
    if lowerbound>=upperbound:
        raise ValueError('the first argument is lower bound, lower bound bigger than upper bound!')
    else:
        return np.nonzero((inarray>lowerbound)|(inarray<upperbound))

def arg_outside(inarray,lowerbound,upperbound):
    if lowerbound>=upperbound:
        raise ValueError('the first argument is lower bound, lower bound bigger than upper bound!')
    else:
        return np.nonzero((inarray<lowerbound)&(inarray>upperbound))
```

thanks to all.

Comment: Do you want a more efficient version of `np.nonzero(inarray<threshold)`?

Comment: You could use `np.where` instead of `nonzero` which I think is more readable.

Comment: yes. I would agree. thanks for comments.

Comment: I think you have the 'or' and 'and' operators interchanged in the 2 functions